# Keyboard shortcut to switch focus from web developer tools in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

Is there a keyboard shortcut to allow you to switch between Chrome Developer Tools and the main window and back again?  I am looking for a shortcut that will work on Windows, MacOSX and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct answer to this.  Unfortunately, all of the keyboard shortcuts for changing the focus are intercepted by Chrome Developer Tools. You can toggle the visibility of Chrome Developer Tools with:

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>
- OSX: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>
- Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>

However once you are in Chrome Developer Tools very few Atom Shortcuts still work, this is maybe something that can be implemented in a package or in `init.coffee`.